# How do I get data to show? My Firebase Realtime Database Still Says Null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
I am trying to sync my Realtime Firebase database with my code.
I currently have Firebase Auth working, and I am able to get user ids, but my Realtime database stays on null. My Firebase Realtime database rules are currently set to true.
Is there something wrong with my code? I am trying to pull in the user id, first name, and last name into the Firebase Database.

```
public class Add_Info_After_Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText FirstName, LastName;
    private ImageButton RegisterInfoButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersReference;

    //Firebase Things//
    String currentUserID;
    //Firebase Things//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__info__after__registration);

        //this is referring to storing username information in firebase//
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        //this is referring to storing username information in firebase//

        FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_info_first_name);
        LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_info_last_name);
        RegisterInfoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.register_submit_button);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        RegisterInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                SaveAccountSetUpInformation();
                SendUserToMainActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SaveAccountSetUpInformation()
    {
        String firstname = FirstName.getText().toString();
        String lastname = LastName.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert first name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert last name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("firstname", firstname);
            userMap.put("lastname", lastname);
            //this is referring to storing username information in firebase//    
            UsersReference.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Your Account is Created Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Error Occured:"+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already set a breakpoint inside `onComplete`? Does it get hit? What happens if you step through that method? What are the values of `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: Does it shows "Your Account is Created Sucessfully"?

Comment: Yes. My account was created successfully. And I do get User ids when they log in.

Comment: UPDATE: This problem is now solved. I noticed my JDK was not updated. Data is now pulling in. Thank you everyone for trying to help.  :)